# Does Evernote change the API validation for the Content-Length?

Tags: evernote

Has Evernote changed the HTTP request header validation in the latest update?
Our API call for getting access token has failed after the update.
It seems the reason of the error is no Content-Length header in the request.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a side-effect of the Evernote's move to the cloud. Google's load balancers do some HTTP request validation that Evernote was not previously doing: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/

So for your case, adding the content-length header should fix the issue.